# Windows: ping's timestamp option

Tags: windows, ping, cmd.exe

The Windows "Shell" (cmd) provides the following option for `ping`:

> **-s**   Count   : Specifies that the Internet Timestamp option in the IP header is used to record the time of arrival for the Echo Request
>   message and corresponding Echo Reply message for each hop. The Count
>   must be a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 4. (→ [source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490968.aspx))

If this is connected with IP's timestamp option (→ [source](http://openmaniak.com/ping.php)) and I get no results except from pinging my own router this means that this is blocked, right? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Maybe it is blocked? You can search some attacks that use the timestamp. Can you try it on `4.2.2.2`? I know they don't block it.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Seems to be blocked at my ISP already. I guess the known potential for misuse explains this.

Comment: +1 to you and whoever can tell you what's going then :)